# Setting a class as a property within another separate class

Tags: c#, class, properties, nullreferenceexception

For my project, I have several classes. Two of those class I would like to tie to together in the following way:
Its a basic budget application.

```
public class Car
{ 
    public int Insurance { get; set; }
    public int Gas { get; set; }
}

public class Budget
{ 
    public Car CarProperty { get; set; }
    public Budget()
    {
        CarProperty = new Car();
    } 
}
```

This may not be possible but I would like to instantiate just the Budget class
like so

```
Budget budget = new Budget();
```

I then want to assign the property of Car through the Car property in Budget for example:

```
budget.CarProperty.Insurance = 500;
```

I don't know if this is possible, if it isn't or I'm doing something totally ridiculous.
In my Manager class with my BLL class library I have a method which returns budget after assigning budget.CarProperty.Insurance = 500;

for example:

```
public class BudgetManager()
{ 
    public void BudgetCreation()
    { 
        Budget budget = new Budget();
        budget.CarProperty.Insurance = 500;
        return budget;
    } 
}
```

Using Nuget

I create a test method,  which creates a new instance of budget

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    Budget budget = new Budget();
    BudgetManager manager = new BudgetManager();
    budget = manager.BudgetCreation();
    Assert.AreEqual(500, budget.CarProperty.Insurance)
}
```

budget.CarProperty.Insurance just comes back as 0 not 500.
Again, im probably missing some small detail and being ignorant of something so please go easy on my

Comment: Your code is showing CarCosts and Budget class. Where is your Car class?

Comment: Classes generally ought to be more self-sustaining.  You ought not have to build them via code external to them.  More generally, I would think Car Costs would just be a category rather than another class, otherwise you could have dozens upon dozens of nearly identical classes

Comment: Yes, it's possible, although you're getting the error because CarProperty of Budget class hasn't been instanciated, change public AddResponse() to public Budget(), that way you're defining a constructor to your class.

Comment: Accessing a property of a property is possible and not ridiculous. Have you tried? What makes you think it is not possible? What prompted the question is what I am getting at I guess.

Comment: I edited my previous code to get rid of some errors, I had from trying to type out the question too quickly.  I tried to explain where exactly i'm having issues and that is within my test class. It is not recognizing that I assigned the property and basically shows zero when I view my locals window within visual studio

Comment: Plutonix,  
Ok, thank you for that. That sounds like a principle I will definitely follow to keep my code flexible and maintainable. I just want to make sure I understand what you mean. I'm not sure what type of container I would use for it or what you by that exactly.  Sorry if it a bad question, I'm still learning– Student 14 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would agree with @Plutonix with regards to Classes being self-sustaining... but, If I understand you, correctly, you want to be able to do this:

```
budget.CarProperty.Insurance = 500;
```

without having to do this, first:

```
budget.CarProperty = new Car();
```

In that case, you could do this:

```
public class Car
{ 
    public int Insurance { get; set; }
    public int Gas { get; set; }
}

public class Budget
{ 
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public Budget()
    {
        Car = new Car();
    } 
}

public class BudgetManager
{ 
    public static Budget CreateBudget(int insurance)
    { 
        Budget budget = new Budget();
        budget.Car.Insurance = insurance;
        return budget;
    } 
}
```

So, when you run the Unit Test, you'll get your desired behavior:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() 
{

    int insurance = 500;
    Budget b = BudgetManager.CreateBudget(insurance);

    Assert.AreEqual(insurance, b.Car.Insurance);
}
```

Unit Tested the code, and it's working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I wanted to do.  About what you said regard, "In general, I would agree with @Plutonix with regards to Classes being self-sustaining."  I was wondering if it is generally not good programming to have a class as a property within a class.  I want to make sure I have code that is flexible, maintainable, and testable, so it doing this is generally bad, I want to make sure I do not do it in the future.

Comment: In general, you'll frequently find classes represented as Properties within another class. 
In your example, someone may argue all budget items should be in the budget class. E.g: You may have a more-generic class of BudgetItem that has the Properties Category, Cost, etc... and BudgetItem would be represented as IEnumerable<BudgetItem> BudgetItems {set; get; }